# Is there a usage limit on Spotify API?

Tags: api, spotify

I want to search track information and add item to my playlist using SPOTIFY API

SPOTIFY API has a using limit?

if it exists, Can you tell me about points by api used

Comment: google "spotify api limits" .....

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is a rate limit, although the [documentation](https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/web-api/guides/rate-limits/) does not specify any concrete values:

> Spotify’s API rate limit is calculated based on the number of calls that your app makes to Spotify in a rolling 30 second window. If your app exceeds the rate limit for your app then you’ll begin to see 429 error responses from Spotify’s Web API, and you may hear from users about unexpected behavior that they have noticed while using your app. The limit varies depending on whether your app is in development mode or extended quota mode.

If you run into rate limiting you can get in touch with Spotify to request an increase for the application you are building and/or maintaining.